# How to sum 68 differents columns?

Tags: text-processing

I have 68 data files. All of them have the same values in the first column, but different values in the second column.

I need to create a new file containing the first column and ANOTHER COLUMNS who is the sum of all second columns.

How can I do this?

---

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: It is a three columns file

Comment: If you add the sample data to your question instead of a comment, you can use formatting to make it more readable.

Comment: Then what's the problem Lodvert ?

Comment: I don't know how to sum many column of data. That's my problem. note that I am using a linux system

Comment: Could you please add a sample of two files (say, with three lines each) and what output you expect to your question? It is not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: Yes, without a sample we can't really help. For example, we need to know the format of the numbers, the format of the file (is it space separated? Tab separated? Something else?) and the output you'd expect. Do you want the total sum? The sum for each of the values shown in the first column? All of this will become clear if you post a simple example showing ~3 files and ~3 columns and the output you'd like for them.

Answer (score 0):

Easy done with `awk`

```
awk '{sum[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in sum)print i sum[i]}' file{1..68}.data
```

Comment: That assumes the values in the first column are unique and it won't preserve the order, it would be better to index on FNR and use two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{f1[FNR] = $1; f2[FNR] += $2}
     FNR > n {n = FNR}
     END {for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print f1[i], f2[i]}' ./*.data
```

Comment: This just popped up in the review queue. Stephane, _you_ should know how to answer on SE, so please...

Comment: @countermode, `awk` code is generally self-explanatory. Any addition to that would be useless paraphrasing.

Comment: Lol! - no, not for beginners I'm afraid, and not all of us don't speak awk fluently as you do either...

Comment: @countermode, I'm not going to teach the basic principles of awk scripting (which IMO is the only prerequisite for understanding that answer) in [all the awk answers I give](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+awk). Please feel free to edit the answer to show me how you would improve it.

Comment: awk '{f1[FNR] = $1; f2[FNR] += $2}
     FNR > n {n = FNR}
     END {for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print f1[i], f2[i]}' ./*.data  (It's working ... Thank you to all.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.